# get_template_directory_uri() returning wrong URI after defining WP_HOME / WP_SITEURL

Tags: wordpress

In `functions.php`, we are setting the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` like so:

```
define('WP_HOME', ...);
define('WP_SITEURL', ...);
```

I can verify that the value of `...` above is correct.

However, `get_template_directory_uri()` returns the **wrong** URI.

What needs to be changed to ensure that `get_template_directory_uri()` is using the correct URI based on the value of `WP_HOME` / `WP_SITEURL`?

Comment: Raphael, are you trying to serve the wordpress site in a new domain? Is that why you are trying to force the WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL? If so you should instead update the wp_options and wp_posts post table entries replacing the old links base url with the new one. Or use a plugin like duplicator.

Comment: @immendes, it's because we have one codebase for dev & stage with environment variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you please add following at wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME', ...);
define('WP_SITEURL', ...);
```

Comment: Definitely solved my issue, I didn't know defining then in `wp-config.php` would be different from defining them in `functions.php`!