# Local site redirects to live

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, local, live

My LocalWP staging website keeps redirecting me to the live web + cant even log into the wp admin.
This is a custom wordpress website. I’m using LocalWP, made a copy of the website using duplicator.

How could I fix this error? Has anyone had familiar issues?
Thank you

I browsed the files but couldnt really find anything that could help

Comment: Repeat your Duplicator restore operation, and be sure to specify your staging website URL when doing so. What you have sounds like you specified the live site URL when restoring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get\_template\_directory\_uri() returning wrong URI after defining WP\_HOME / WP\_SITEURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544781/get-template-directory-uri-returning-wrong-uri-after-defining-wp-home-wp-sit)

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two options:

The best way is to change site URL in database. Go to table `wp_options` and find a row with `option_name` equals to `siteurl` than change it to your local site URL (it's often be `http://localhost`), make same changes to `home` row.

Else, if you can't change the URL in the DB, there is an option to put the setting into config file, but be careful, if you upload the file to the live server, it will stop working. Put these two lines into your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue before.

The best way to start is by going through a basic check list of things to check.

1. If you have cpanel access. Go to your database, and click on the wp_options tables. Once there, if you go to option_id for siteurl and enter your local host / local site url details here. You'll also need to go to option_id for home, and enter your local sites home page url. If you've copied or installed a backup of your live site, these details will have your live sites details to start with, and will cause your local site to redirect to your live site, until these details are changed to your local host /local sites url details.

You'll also want to go through other option_id's, like the uploads path, as you'll need to set the correct url for this to, if your going to be uploading images.

You'll also want to make sure that your .htaccess file is correct as well, as this is normally the other main one, that can cause your local site redirecting to the live site.

This may help if you want a basic .htaccess file for your local wordpress site to get you going:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /public_html/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /public_html/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please note this .htaccess file will only work if your wordpress root directory is under the public_html folder.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress database and update the wp_options table's siteurl and home rows to your staging URL.

Verify that your wp-config.php file in the root directory of your WordPress installation doesn't contain any hard-coded references to the live website's URL.

Look for lines like define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.istacksolution.com'); or define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.istacksolution.com'); and update them with your staging URL.

Comment: Hi, it's better to use some formatting for code. Please read [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)